# Adding or removing objects from an ObservableCollection takes significant time especially when there are more objects in the collection

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, observablecollection

I am working with Xamarin.Forms. I have `ObservableCollection` that I am using as an `ItemsSource`. When I try to add a new item to the `ObservableCollection`, it is taking significant time especially when there are lots of items already in the collection. This happens, for example, when there are 200 items in the `ObservableCollection`. When I try to add one more item, it takes 13 to 15 seconds just to add an object.

My code snippet is as follows:

```cs
var page = new AddItemPopup(async (roomItem, isOpen) =>
{
    await Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        roomItem.Item.CId = CRoom.Room.CId;
        roomItem.Item.RId = CRoom.Room.RId;
        roomItem.Item.RoomUniqueId = CurrentRoom.Room.RoomUniqueId;
        await _rs.SaveRoomItem(roomItem.Item);
        await App.RunOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            ItemDetails.Add(roomItem);
        });
        CC.ItemCount++;
        CRoom.TotalItems++;
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAllAsync();
        ItemsTabTitle = $"Items ({ItemDetails.Count - 1})";
    
        if (isOpen)
        {
            await ItemTapped(roomItem);
        }
    });
}, CC.CId);

if (PopupNavigation.Instance.PopupStack.Count == 0)
{
    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(page);
}
```

> ItemDetails.Add(roomItem);

It takes a lot more time than normal.

I have seen that `ObservableCollection` takes a lot more time in adding or removing items compared to a `List`, but it is very important for updating the UI. How we can improve the performance when using `ObservableCollection`? I have seen a similar post (not exactly the same) where the author was facing the same issue and the suggested solution is to use BackgroundWorker but here I don't know how to utilize it.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/db0ec5ea-55cd-4f32-b1af-256e946b2a2f/populating-observablecollection-is-slow?forum=wpf

Is there any way I can use a `List` object and whenever I add or remove an item from my `List` my `ObservableCollection` gets updated (without creating a new instance everytime)?

Comment: how are you determining that specific code is the problem?  Have you profiled it, or are you just relying on observing how long the app takes to respond?

Comment: I have implemented Stopwatch() to measure time.

Comment: simply adding a single object to a collection should not take that long.  Without being able to run the code its difficult to say what might be wrong

Comment: Is there any way I use the List collection but still able to update the UI? I tried replacing ObservableCollection with a List object, it is very fast. The only problem is UI is not updating. I have to reload the page.

Comment: if that is the case it seems like the UI update is what is actually taking up the time

Comment: The problem shouldn't be the `ObservableCollection` but rather it sounds like the way you use it is causing the issue, or there is some problem with your UI setup in general. You should provide all relevant bits of your code and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because with the current information it's hard to tell what might be wrong. Where are you using the collection?

Comment: There is something about these items, that takes significant time per item, for all items in collection, whenever the view updates. You’ll need to show all xaml and code that might run when the collection’s view is updated. I agree with ewerspej that a repo that others can examine and run, is needed.